# Silent Install of Visual Basic 2010 Express with Key

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I've been asked to perform an install of VB 2010 Express on a number of our machines. I would typically do software installs with a .msi however there doesn't seem to be an installer .msi for VB2010Express. I have dowloaded the Visual Studio 2010 .iso, copied the VBExpress folder to a share and can install the software fine. I believe doing a setup.exe /q will do a silent install, I would however like to insert the activation key as well to avoid having to registering the program on every machine once it is installed.

Is there a way to do this, or do I face doing a next > next > next > install > copy > paste key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the VBExpress folder you copied from the .ISO you will find a setup.sdb file
Open this file with a text editor and locate the following section 
[Product Key]
;Add your registed product key you received from Microsoft in the format
xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx

Save the file to your install point

Now you can run a silent install (setup.exe /q /norestart) and the product should install with the registration already completed

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if my answer comes to late, but there is a way to install Visual Studio 2010 Express via msi

1. Download `vb_web.exe` from microsoft.com
2. Unpack `vb_web.exe`
3. Open `baseline.dat` with any text editor
4. Under `[vs_setup.dll]` you find the URL-Paramter (something like that: URL=fwlink/?LinkId=165113
5. Go to `go.microsoft.com\fwlink\?LinkId=165113` (switch 165113 for the correct ID from the baseline.dat)
6. Download `ixpvb.exe`
7. Unpack it and use `vs_setup.msi` for silent installation

Necessary Parameters:

`vsextui=1` (makes the .msi think it has been run from the .exe. Without this, you get an error)

`PIDKEY= (you need this to give your Registration Key to the Installer)`

This also works for all other Instances of Microsoft Visual Studio Express

[**Source**](http://www.itninja.com/software/microsoft/visual-basic-2010-express-edition/10-1588)